# Some of my iPad pages won't rotate/resize correctly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, interface-builder

I have an application that I submitted to the app Store.  2/5 of my pages (tabs) would not rotate/resize correctly.  Thus I turned off rotation.  Thus Apple rejected my application.  So I went back to the drawing board.  Still those two pages fail to rotate correctly.

Can I reposition my text fields and such programmatically considering that Interface Builder doesn't work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Every control is a subclass of UIView, which has the frame property to determine its position inside its superview. You can override willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: in your view controller subclass to reposition your views and controls.

That said, unless you have some really novel layout in your application, the struts and springs autosizing you can set up in Interface Builder should work for you.